# iOS: connectionDidFinishLoading is not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton, appdelegate, nsmutableurlrequest

I would like to call a webService from my `MainViewController.m` which is located in my `DataManagement.m` class. What I do is create a singleton and launch it with this line:

```
[[DataManagement sharedManager] callWebService:url withBytes:bytes];
```

It works properly. The `connectionDidFinishLoading` is called in that case.

But if I want to check Internet with another `Reachability.m` class (the callback block returns the error as nil. So it means that there is an Internet connection). When I then launch the same code, the `connectionDidFinishLoading` method is never called. Do I have to use a delegate, or something else?

**DataManagement.m**

```
+ (instancetype) sharedManager
{
    static DataManagement *sharedManager = nil;

    if (sharedManager == nil)
    {
        sharedManager = [[self alloc] init];
    }
    return sharedManager;
}

- (void)callWebService:(NSString *)url withBytes:(NSString *) bytes
{
    NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    NSString *url_string = [bytes stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[url stringByAppendingString: url_string]]];
    [request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:timeOut];
    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
 ...
}
```

**MainViewController.m**

*Doesn't work:*

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    ...
    [Reachability checkInternetConnectivityWithUrl: url_server WithSuccessCompletion:^(NSError *error) {
        if (error == nil)
        {
            [[DataManagement sharedManager] callWebService:url withBytes:bytes];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"No internet connection");
        }
    }];
    ...
}
```

*Works:*

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    ...
    [[DataManagement sharedManager] callWebService:url withBytes:bytes];
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your using correct only for checking internet connection, but its connected or not check using this function. It will work fine.

```
- (BOOL)connected
  {
    Reachability *reachability = [Reachability      
                     reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    NetworkStatus networkStatus = [reachability 
                       currentReachabilityStatus];
    return networkStatus != NotReachable;
  }



-(void)viewDidLoad
    {
      ...
     if ([self connected])
         {
                [[DataManagement sharedManager] callWebService:url 
       withBytes:bytes];
         }
         else
         {
            NSLog(@"No internet connection");
         }
    }

 }
```

Comment: The problem with this is that if this is a LAN connection with an antenna well connected but without any server reachable, the reachability says it is reachable, and in fact it is not. I don't like the [Reachability      
                     reachabilityForInternetConnection];